# Android Studio failed to initialize editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am facing the following problem. [image]

I am using Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2 on a MacPro Monterey Apple chip.

I've tried the following

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Clean > Rebuild
- Clean > Rebuild > Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Remove Android Studio Completely and re-install it.

Comment: Try it once. Close the project and go to the project folder. Show hidden files. Delete .idea and .gradle folders. Again open the project in android studio.

Comment: I've tried that also @AnkitKumarMaurya

Answer (score 4):

[image: Please upgrade your gradle version and android gradle version]

1- Please upgrade your gradle version and android gradle version.

2- Invalidate your cache/file system

*(( BONUS ))*

- Try to upgrade your Kotlin version to make sure you are compatible with new version
- Also check your JAVA_HOME environment and make sure to use Android Studio version.